# Installing gdata in R

Tags: r, gdata

I tried to install package `gdata` with the following command, but got the message that follows:

```
install.packages(pkgs="gdata")  
Warning in install.packages(pkgs = "gdata") :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.3/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages(pkgs = "gdata") : unable to install packages
```

Seems the directory "library" should be writable, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have have administrator privileges on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I do have admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can install in a custom folder by specifying the `lib` argument of `install.packages`. Try something like `lib = "C:/Users/you/Documents/R/3.1.3/"` or whatever folder you have writable.

Answer (score 0):

If R is installed on a Remote Desktop, or somewhere else where R is having difficulty automatically installing those folders, you will need to specify where to put the files. The first step will be creating these folders, for example in your C:/ or D:/ drive. Preferably create an R folder, with a version folder (3.1.3) that you will be using. To know which version of R your using if using R studio, hold control while opening R studio.
Once these folders are created, just use the following code, inputting your path to the version folder (3.1.3). For example:

```
lib = "D:/R/3.1.3"
install.packages("gdata", lib)
```

And then to load your package.

```
library("gdata", lib.loc= lib)
```